# Picasso loads landscape image but doesn't load portrait into marker's info window

Tags: android, google-maps, picasso, marker

I have a map activity where I want to have customised info window for my markers.
In that window I want to load a picture from a file, and add some additional text (which I will add later).

The problem is, when I have a picture file in landscape mode, the photo loads and shown in the marker's info window with the right dimensions. 
However, if the file is in portrait mode, the info window appears with the right dimension (indeed portrait), but there is no picture shown.
I checked that the portrait image file exists, it has the correct file path, but I can't find out why portrait pictures do not show.

Here is my code:

```
        // Initializing the custom info window as per info_window.xml
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
                    mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.markerImageView);

                    for (Picture picture : mPictureList) {
                        if (picture.getMarker().equals(marker)) {
                            String path = picture.getPicturePath();
                            int width = 160;
                            int height = 90;
                            ExifInterface data = null;
                            try {
                                data = new ExifInterface(path);
                                String orientation = data.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
                                // 1 for landscape, 3 for landscape upside down
                                // 6 for portrait, 8 is portrait upside down
                                if (orientation.equalsIgnoreCase("6") || orientation.equalsIgnoreCase("8")) {
                                    width = 90;
                                    height = 160;
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // setting the new dimensions in dp
                            mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, height, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                            mImageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, width, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                            mImageView.requestLayout();

                            Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this)
                                    .load("file://" + path)
                                    .resize(width, height)
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .into(mImageView);
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "getInfoContents: Didn't find any picture with that marker");
                        }
                    }
                    return view;
                }
            });
        }
```

And the info_window.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/markerImageView"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Jonas Lochmann, removing the centerCrop() didn't help. Still no image shown in portrait mode (the dimensions of the info window were set to portrait). Btw, I think centerCrop() is important in case the picture wasn't taken in 16:9 ratio (which is the ratio I am setting for the info window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem.
I was using the latest version of picasso 2.3.2 which has an issue with displaying images (as per https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/530)
I switched to version 2.2.0 and the problem got solved.

P.S. Version 2.4.0 should fix the problem described above.